# Use Mithril and Tooltipster

Tags: jquery, tooltipster, mithril.js

I'd like to include interactive content in a tooltip [that's created using Tooltipster]. A simple example:

```
$('a').tooltipster({
    contentAsHTML: true,
    content: '<span><a href="#">Tooltip click me</a></span>',
    theme: 'tooltipster-light',
    interactive: true
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qrbsug8r/2/

The goal is to have the "Tooltip click me" link in the Tooltip content trigger a typical Mithril draw cycle.

My questions are how do I render the tooltip content using standard Mithril, and how do I hookup the onclick event? For example, if I were not using Tooltipster I might do:

```
    m('span', m('a', {
        'href': '#',
        'onclick': ctrl.someFunc
    }))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Stephan mentioned, you want to use the config option to get the tooltipster functionality. Since you have an href, you could just use that and capture the route:

```
m('a', {
  config: function (el) {
    $(el).tooltipster({
      contentAsHTML: true,
      content: '<span><a href="/someAction">Tooltip click me</a></span>',
      theme: 'tooltipster-light',
      interactive: true
    });
  }
});
```

if you didn't want to have a route change, you could add a jQuery click listener inside the config function:

```
m('a', {
  config: function (el) {
    $(el).tooltipster({
      contentAsHTML: true,
      content: '<span><a href="/#">Tooltip click me</a></span>',
      theme: 'tooltipster-light',
      interactive: true
    });
    $(el).find('a').on('click', ctrl.callback);
  }
});
```

Because this isn't an event handler registered through mithril, you'd manually have to redraw the UI inside ctrl.callback using m.redraw() (or start/endComputation).

Answer (score 0):

You might do the following

```
m('span', [
  m('a', {
    href: '#',
    onclick: function() { ctrl.tooltopVisible = true }
  }),
  ctrl.tooltipVisible ? m('.tooltip', 'Click me') : ''
])
```

Comment: But where does that code go? The tooltip content (i.e. the above code block) is not in the DOM until the user mouses over the element. At that time, Tooltipster will render the content.

Comment: I just understand that you want not to use tooltipster. You have to use the `config`-callback if you want to do that.